# Error function--How to take the limit?

Tags: calculus

How to take the limit of this expression. 
$$\lim_{\Delta t\to\ 0} \frac{1}{2 \Delta t} erf(\frac{x-z}{(4D \Delta t)^{1/2}}) $$
 where $|x-z|<\epsilon$ and  $\epsilon>0$. Also $D$ is a constant and positive.

Thanks.